# OpenGL program doesn't show a triangle

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-buffer, vertex-array-object

I am following a tutorial on OpenGL in C++ and for some reason the exact same code doesn't work for me.
It is supposed to display a triangle, but it doesn't show anything.Just a blank screen.
Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include"GL/glew.h"

#include"GLFW/glfw3.h"

static unsigned int compileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& shader)
{
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = shader.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, NULL);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result) {
        char log[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, 512, NULL, log);
        std::cout << "Compiling shader error:\n" << log << std::endl;
    }

    return id;
}

static unsigned int createShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader)
{
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = compileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = compileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    int result;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result) {
        char log[512];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 512, NULL, log);
        std::cout << "linking shader error:\n" << log << std::endl;
    }

    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;
}

void keyCallBack(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);    
}

int main()
{   
    int width = 0, height = 0;

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "Test", nullptr, nullptr);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);  
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallBack);

    float triangle[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
         0.0f,  0.5f,
         0.5f, -0.5f
    };

    GLuint buffer = 0;  
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle), triangle, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); 

    std::string vertexShader = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_Position = position;\n"
    "}\n";

    std::string fragmentShader = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n";

    unsigned int program = createShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    glUseProgram(program);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I really don't understand why it is not working.The triangle's positions look correct.`glVertexAttribPointer` also looks correct.I can't find any errors in the compiling and linking of the shaders and their sources..
I also get zero errors when compiling and linking them..

Comment: Are you checking for `glError`? From what I see, you're lacking a VAO which is mandatory in a core profile.

Comment: @BDL i removed all calls to glfwWindowHint() and now it works.

Comment: But i don't understand why it works without them.

Comment: It works because in modern OpenGL you have to use a VAO. This wasn't the case in old versions. When you remove the "core", you revert to an old OpenGL version which doesn't require VAOs. I would highly recommend that you stay with a core profile and integrate VAOs. (should be 2-3 lines of code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by `GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE`. If you use a core profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context), then you have to use a named [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object), because the default VAO (0) is not valid.

Either use a compatibility profile:

```cpp
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
```

or create a VAO before specifying the array of vertex attribute data:

```cpp
GLuint VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```